# .NET - Security Frameworks for .NET

Tags: java, .net, spring, security, frameworks

Does anyone know of any security frameworks for .NET?

By security framework, I am referring to a framework consisting of a set of libraries and APIs containing code which can be used to improve the security of the application being developed overall.

So far, I have only identified Spring.NET.  I have found other frameworks for .NET such as Castle MonoRail, however it is not exactly directed towards solving security issues.

To give you an example, a Java programmer can make use of the following security frameworks:

1. Apache Shiro (Java)
2. JAAS (Java)
3. JGuard (Java)
4. JSecurity (Java)
5. PicketBox (Java)
6. Spring Security (Java)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know those frameworks but from a quick glance at Apache Shiro and Spring Security I get that you are looking for something that will do *cryptography*, *session management*, *authentication* and *authorization*. Unfortunately I don't know any frameworks that will do that for you except what's built into .NET by default.

**Cryptography** is provided by the [`System.Security.Cryptography` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx).

**Authentication** and **authorization** are provided by default by ASP.Net, as Windows, Forms or password authentication. See for example the [ASP.NET authentication and authorization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98950/ASP-NET-authentication-and-authorization) article on CodeProject.

**Session management** is also built into ASP.Net. For example, see [ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks.  I have search a lot on the internet, however I can't seem to find any security frameworks built specifically for .NET.  It seems that the .NET framework provides all these functions on its own.