# Spring Security Domain Object ACLs in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security

Does anybody know of any framework in .NET providing functionality similar to Spring Security Domain Object ACLs? I know that a similar question was asked already ([.NET - Security Frameworks for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419147/net-security-frameworks-for-net)), however it seemed rather generic.

I am using NHibernate and Castle Windsor in ASP.NET web applications and I need fine grained permission checking on domain objects without weaving the security code into the domain logic. I have experimented with own implementations based on interceptors and attributes, but the effort and complexity quickly explodes.

I need a framework that allows me to check method access permissions on domain objects which are persisted with NHibernate. Permisson checking should be pluggable as it varies from project to project. Spring Security Domain Object ACLs seem to provide just that, however I am bound to .NET.